# Hyperledger - composer REST API or submit transactions to add/modify assets?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Is it a good idea to create assets through composer REST API? Some examples submit transactions to add/modify assets, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yes, it is, if that's the correct architectural decision for your environment". REST APIs can have big advantages, depending on how you use them for your setup - this [link](https://blog.restcase.com/why-you-should-have-a-rest-api/) should describe some of these  Its no different in many respects from the generic question "should I use REST APIs to do x" - its largely a business / application architecture decision to decide when to use REST APIs - see also the discussion in this [article](https://bbvaopen4u.com/en/actualidad/rest-api-what-it-and-what-are-its-advantages-project-development)  many reasons are due to consistent naming scheme, statefulness, dealing with resources not methods, flexibility, mobility etc. etc.

An example that is often seen is the use of REST APIs from an Angular app, or similar - a example of their use  which can be seen in this Hyperledger Composer 'Letter of Credit' sample application -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications/blob/master/packages/letters-of-credit/src